# numpy array custom dtype for the list of list

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, user-defined-types

I am confusing in using custom dtype of numpy array which is converting the element of the list to be tuple.

```
np.empty (1000, dtype = [('a',int), ('b','S4')])
```

this would result an array with a tuple type, is this part of the code got err? or if it is acutally not possibile to have the custom type to be in list format?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
dtype = np.dtype((int,int))
```